# Why my code does not executes even conditions are true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I want to implement PayPal payment in my app and for that I do:

```
protect_from_forgery except: [:hook]
def hook
params.permit! # Permit all Paypal input params
status = params[:payment_status]

if status == "Pending"
  logger.info("AAAAAAAAA")

  @order = Order.find params[:invoice]
  @order.update_attributes notification_params: params, status: status, transaction_id: params[:txn_id], purchased_at: Time.now
end

render nothing: true
```

end

and from PayPal I get these params:

```
Parameters: {"mc_gross"=>"1.00", "invoice"=>"10", "protection_eligibility"=>"Eligible", "address_status"=>"unconfirmed", "payment_date"=>"08:13:55 Dec 01, 2016 PST", "payment_status"=>"Pending" ... }
```

How you can see my `payment_status` equals to "Pending", but my code does not execute and I do not know why, even my condition `status == "Pending"` is true.

What is the problem? I do not get my `logger.info` on my logs. How can I fix that?

Comment: what rails version is that?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Rails v4.2

Comment: @AndreyDeineko any suggestions???